# How to deal with Forefront Threat Management Gateway (TMG) for accessing sharepoint services

Tags: ios, sharepoint

How should I access the share point web services in iOS which need to be authenticated by TMG. When I invoke login request it returns login HTML template in response as shown below

[image]

Can we authenticate TMG firewall somehow in iOS. I am not expecting whole source but any help, references will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Finally we got solution to this stuff. By requesting site info using GetWeb method like
    "SOAPAction" : "http:\schemas.microsoft.com\sharepoint\soap\GetWeb"

along with a username, password we received cookies. Then passing these cookies to next share point services we received response and resolved above TMG auth issue.